# How do I include 400 validation errors in drf-spectacular?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, drf-spectacular

I want to view validation details in 400 response as they can be reutrned by the serializer. The serializer can return errors depending on a missing field or invalid value and I want the documentation to indicate which kind of errors can appear with the status code 400. Something like this

200: Success

400: [
{
"organisation_id": [
"This field is required."
]
}
] #include any validation errors that can come from the serializer

My code currently is this

```
@extend_schema(
        summary="Create a new transaction",
        responses={
            201: OpenApiResponse(
                description='Success',
            ),
            400: OpenApiResponse(
                description='Bad request. One or more errors occured.',
            ),
        },
    )
```

And currently this outputs
200: Success

400: Bad request. One or more errors occurred.

Is there something like

```
400: OpenApiResponse(description=customSerializerErrors,
 ), #customSerializerErrors is something i hope gets errors from the serializer
```

Comment: you want to override the error message right? please confirm

Comment: I want to show the error messages in the document. I want them to appear next to the status code. These are the same error messages that the serializer will return.

Comment: sorry can you please add an example

Comment: I have tried to add an example of what i want to achieve but I don't know if it exists or can be done @VishalPandey

Comment: 400: description=customSerializerErrors you can add this i don't think we can do the one you are saying for response you can add in string like this "OpenApiResponse(description=customSerializerErrors),"

Comment: just add your message in details like this ```{"status_code": 400, "detail":"OpenApiResponse(description=customSerializerErrors,)."}```

Comment: see if it works for reference see this docs https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/

Comment: @VishalPandey I think I am not explaining my request well. customSerializerErrors is a placeholder for the errors coming from the serializers and that is what I don't know how to get. The question is how do I get these errors from the serializers first, then second display them in the status code description

Comment: we can't do that in django. django returns static statement which we can override it but on place holder we can't update error from django

Comment: Do you mean that the validation errors cannot be documented in swagger documentation?

Comment: it will display the error but can't change dynamically 
you want like on place holder error statement should display dynamically

Comment: I want to display ALL errors that will raise with status code 400. This is not in the try-out section remember. I am showing all response status codes in my sample code and I want to show each status code as in my sample code but for 400, I want to show the errors that will be given by the serializer with 400

Comment: we can't do that because django only return ```bad request``` as far as i know we cant do that in django

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238982/discussion-between-vishal-pandey-and-anjayluh).

Comment: I am using a serializer using drf. And this returns all the validation errors using serializer.is_valid so yes, it is possible in django. My problem is displaying them in the swagger documentation as part of the responses

Comment: okay so i am trying to find it out if get that i'll defiantly add here

Answer (score 3):

`drf-spectacular` works on the basis of serializers.

`OpenApiResponse` is a convenience wrapper that is not needed most of the time. In fact here, it is probably not doing what you expect. You would need to give `OpenApiResponse(response=SomeSerializer)`, otherwise you are saying there is no response body, because the default is `None` == no response.

You likely want to do this:

```py
@extend_schema(
        summary="Create a new transaction",
        responses={
            201: YourSerializer,
            400: YourErrorSerializer,
        },
    )
```

There is no predefined `YourErrorSerializer` because Django's `error_handler` is highly dynamic and cannot be inspected. At the moment you would need to write this `YourErrorSerializer` yourself. Note that this serializer is not actually used, but is merely telling spectacular how the response is structured.